# generate an implicit tuple while calling a function

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates

I want to call a templated function and pass two parameter sets as tuple. But calling this functions needs always manual building the tuple with `std::make_tuple` before passing this as an argument.

Example:

```
template < typename ... OUT, typename ... IN>
void Command( std::tuple<OUT...>, std::tuple<IN...>)
{
}


int main()
{
    // Send Parameter
    uint8_t mode;
    uint16_t addr;

    // Receive Parameter
    uint16_t neighbour0;
    uint16_t neighbour1;

    Command( std::make_tuple( mode, addr ),
             std::make_tuple( neighbour0, neighbour1 ));
}
```

Is there any chance/trick to remove the `std::make_tuple` in the function call so that I can write something like:

```
Command( {mode, addr}, {neighbour0, neighbour1} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the notation

```
Command(mode, addr)(neighbour0, neighbour1);
```

is acceptable, `Command()` could return essentially a function object with a bound first `std::tuple<...>` which would call the actual function when receiving the other arguments. That is the implementation would be something along the lines of

```
template <typename... Out, typename... In>
void realCommand(std::tuple<Out...>, std::tuple<In...>);

template <typename... Out>
auto Command(Out&&... out) {
    return [&](auto&&... in){
        realCommand(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Out>(out)...),
                    std::make_tuple(std::forward<decltype(in)>(in)...));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no, but you could maybe save a little typing with a monstrosity like this:

```
template<class...Ts>
auto _(Ts&&...ts)
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

...

```
Command(_(mode, addr),
        _(neighbour0, neighbour1));
```

The usual warnings apply - just because we can, does not mean we ought to...